# How to get neighborhood name (i.e.: Manhattan, Queens, Brooklyn, etc.)?

Tags: java, android, google-maps

When I use `geocoder` fetch address with lat & long coordinate, the address object does not contain the information for "neighborhood", since the neighborhood is not part of standard address in US. I've checked the `subLocality` and `subAdminArea`, both will be null for most of time. I wonder is there any way to get these information?

Comment: Those aren't neighborhood names.  Those are borough names, which are kind of unique to NYC.  Neighborhood names would be like Chelsea, Hell's Kitchen, Fidi, etc.  And that's kind of arbitrary, neighborhood boundaries aren't legal things, they're descriptions that change over time.  THere's isn't an authoritative way of saying what's in what neighborhood.

Comment: For boroughs though, did you check the county?  A borough is a county and a city that combined.  SO Queens is Queens county, Brooklyn is Kings, etc.

Comment: @GabeSechan Thanks, not too familiar with NY, but the county is a bit broad, i.e if I set my location to SOMA in SF, the country will just be San Francisco County, :)

Comment: That's a distinctly NYC thing with counties. Nyc actually has 5 counties inside it. If you want boroughs, it works. If you want neighborhoods, you aren't likely to find a good source because the definition of a neighborhood is so fuzzy